# Shell conexion MySQL ubuntu

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-workbench, shell

Desde que instalae ubuntu 19.10 no consigo conectarme con la terminal al mysql remoto con el comando:
"mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u admin -p"

me pide la contraseña pero cuando la inserto demoro como 10 minutos hasta que conecta. Curiosamente el workbeach hace lo mismo.

He probado infinidad de cosas, probe a meter un booteable live y ejecutando el mismo comando a la misma maquina remota conecta rapidamente. Por lo que descarto algo del route y algo de la maquina remota. Además esta maquina tiene deshabilitado el firewall.

Sin embargo, al MySQL localhost conecta rapidamente, solo me ocurre cuando quiero conectarme alguna maquina remota fuera de mi red.

Estuve indigando sobre DNS etc... desistale resolv, pero sigo con el mismo problema.

Como podria saber lo que esta ocurriendo?, por que el log del ubuntu tampoco me arroja ningun error.

Que prueba podria hacer?

gracias!

**mi tabla de enrutamiento es esta.**

default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    600

link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000

192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600

---

Comment: Y antes funcionaba diferente? Al conectarte desde otra terminal / otro OS / otra versión, funcionaba diferente? DNS no tiene importancia porque no estás resolviendo una URL sino que ya tienes la IP. El problema es del enrutamiento de tus paquetes hacia el servidor remoto. La pregunta es: alguna vez te has conectado rápidamente a ese host?

Comment: he probado de diferentes terminales con otro usuario root, y ocurre el mismo problema. si me conecto desde otro OS funciona. Con otro OS en mi caso ubuntu live si conecta rapidamente sin problema.

Comment: Con otro OS en mi caso ubuntu live si conecta rapidamente sin problema.

Comment: Es que 10 minutos es una situación extrema. Casi que está esperando uno o varios timeouts hasta que llega a la opción correcta. Revisa que sólo esté arriba la interfaz web WAN (la que te da salida a Internet) para ver si así mejora (dependiendo del orden en que suben y el peso, tiende a usar una u otra).

Comment: Como puedo ver eso ?

Comment: incluye en tu pregunta la salida de `ip addr sh`